# Issues with adding user to LDAP server in Java using JNDI

Tags: java, ldap, jndi, openldap

I'm having an issue with adding a user to my LDAP server in Java.

Here's what my code looks like

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.jar.Attributes;

import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.naming.directory.Attribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttribute;
import javax.naming.directory.BasicAttributes;
import javax.naming.directory.DirContext;
import javax.naming.directory.InitialDirContext;

    public class LdapProgram {  


            public static void main(String[] args) {  
              String dn = "";
              String password = "";
              Properties properties = new Properties();
              properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
              properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://127.0.0.1");
              properties.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION,"none");
              properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL,password);
              properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS,dn);
                // TODO code application logic here  

                          // entry's DN 
           String entryDN = "uid=test_user,ou=people,dc=test123,dc=com";  

            // entry's attributes  

            Attribute cn = new BasicAttribute("cn", "tester");  
            Attribute uid = new BasicAttribute("uid", "tester");  
            Attribute gecos = new BasicAttribute("gecos", "test");  
            Attribute oc = new BasicAttribute("objectClass");  
            oc.add("top");  
            oc.add("person");  
            oc.add("organizationalPerson");  
            oc.add("inetOrgPerson");  
            DirContext ctx = null;  

            try {  
                // get a handle to an Initial DirContext  
                ctx = new InitialDirContext(properties);  

                // build the entry  
                BasicAttributes entry = new BasicAttributes();  
                entry.put(cn);  
                entry.put(uid);  
                entry.put(gecos);  

                entry.put(oc);  

                // Add the entry  

                ctx.createSubcontext(entryDN, entry);  
      //          System.out.println( "AddUser: added entry " + entryDN + ".");  

            } catch (NamingException e) {  
                System.err.println("AddUser: error adding entry.\n" + e);  
            }  
         }  
    }
```

Here is the error code I get: javax.naming.AuthenticationNotSupportedException: [LDAP: error code 8 - modifications require authentication]; remaining name 'uid=test_user,ou=people,dc=test123,dc=com'

I'm not understanding why it's saying it requires authentication when I'm already binded to the server with the admin user and password.

Comment: I guess your "dn" for authentication is wrong, usually it point to the admin user inside the LDAP. ex. cn=admin,dc=example,dc=com

Comment: A blank DN isn't going to work, and neither is 'none' security.

Comment: My dn is cn=admin,dc=test123,dc=com, and it seems to be binded already.

Comment: According to the JNDI documentation, you definitely can use 'none' as security. And my DN & Pass are blank here for security.
 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/ldap/security/ldap.html states:

Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION(in the API reference documentation) ("java.naming.security.authentication"). 
Specifies the authentication mechanism to use. For the Sun LDAP service provider, this can be one of the following strings: "none", "simple", sasl_mech, where sasl_mech is a space-separated list of SASL mechanism names. See the next section for a description of these strings.

Comment: @tobeydw Yes, you can use `none`, but not when you are doing modifications. For this particular use-case, you should try `simple`.